# chart:chart not plotting the example

Tags: chart.js

This Meteor client code tries to get the chart.js [example](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/) to work but it is not plotting any thing. i.e. blank page.
Package: chart:chart
Any idea why and how to get the plot to show on the page? Thanks

```js
Template.jack.onRendered(function () {
  console.log('jack rendered');
  var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
      datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
          'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
      }]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero:true
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<template name="jack">
  <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</template>
// element inspector shows:
 <canvas id="myChart" width="359" height="359" style="width: 400px; height: 400px;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Is 'jack rendered' displayed in your console?

Comment: Yes. it is printing in the console.